# Render Dynamically Created React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to dynamically render few SVG icons as React components, below is the sample of the `Icon` file.

```
module.exports = {
    AR: React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="11" viewBox="0 0 20 11">
                </svg>
            );
        }
    }),
    AU: React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="11" viewBox="0 0 20 11">
                </svg>
            );
        }
    }),
    ----few other components
}
```

then require this file as,

```
var Icons = require('./Icons');
```

then tried to dynamically render the component based on the prop value like this, but it's not rendering the component as expected.

```
<i className="footer-img">{() => Icons[this.props.country.code]}</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need arrow fund and `React.createClass`

```
<i className="footer-img">{Icons[this.props.country.code]}</i>

 module.exports = {
    AR: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="11" viewBox="0 0 20 11"></svg>,
    AU: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="11" viewBox="0 0 20 11"></svg>,
    ----few other components
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save svg components directly on your icons object keys and using it like a common component, try this:

```
module.exports = {
  AR: () => (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="20"
      height="11"
      viewBox="0 0 20 11"
    ></svg>
  ),
  AU: () =>(
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="20"
      height="11"
      viewBox="0 0 20 11"
    ></svg>
  )
};
```

and then require this and use it:

```
var Icons = require('./Icons');

const YourApp = ({ country }) => {
      const IconComponent = Icons[country.code];

      return (
        <i className="footer-img">
          {<IconComponent />}
        </i>
      );
    };
```